# Block explorer with testnet raw hex data

Tags: transactions, blockchain, testnet, blockexplorer

Blockchain.info allows you to look at the raw hex of a transaction. But it doesn't have testnet functionality. Blockexplorer allows you to look at testnet, but I can't find a way to show the hex dump.

Any solutions?

Comment: I collected all below answers in the linked community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late, but here's an example of using Blockr.io on testnet with raw hex dump:

http://tbtc.blockr.io/api/v1/tx/raw/5bb4f41ad7ac687db5126cb66a4971100f4137a3056d85ee27343ce429dbe4bb

Comment: Blockr isn't available after Coinbase acquired it. Try this: https://testnet.smartbit.com.au/tx/5bb4f41ad7ac687db5126cb66a4971100f4137a3056d85ee27343ce429dbe4bb

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functioning Testnet Tx Hex decoder 
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/decodetx/

Answer (score 0):

You can also get raw transaction on bitaps.com testent explorer

https://tbtc.bitaps.com/raw/transaction/567661ea8e747e3a83ddfa32006a2e9505f9ad0c15abb552181c5eb399dcc385